# How to split each digit of a number into different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, numbers

I want something like `SELECT splitDigits(123456789) as digits` to return:

```sql
 digits 
-------
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
```

---

What I really need

I'm trying to make [this validation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42957/c%C3%B3mo-validar-un-ruc-de-per%C3%BA) (Perú's RUC ID) in a stored procedure: [image]

I'm trying to avoid loops so I'm stuck in the first step, which is to grab the first 10 digits and multiply each digit by a fixed scalar that depends on the position, then I have to sum all those multiplications.

It's basically vector multiplication, and I'm trying to construct a vector from the first 10 digit of an 11-digit-number.

Comment: the image is not totally clear how you need to use it..you should explain the algoritm beter.

Comment: @RaymondNijland In the image, the arrows from top to bottom implies multiplication by digits, the scalars ( 5 4 3 2 7 6 5 4 3 2 ) are fixed

Comment: @RaymondNijland Then I have to sum all the multiplications.

After that there's some trivial calculations with the result of the sum, applying some modulus and complements, but it's out of the scope of this question.

Comment: *"Then I have to sum all the multiplications."* More or less like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/29), i was indeed not sure which `%` in image meant..

Comment: Check mine answer.. i assume the final result should be 8..

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Solutions *never* belong in the question. If you want to post an answer summarizing the solutions, that is fine, but do make sure that the answer is actually adding something new to the post. A mere summary of what already exists on the page is not useful. Someone can just read the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(3987654321, idx, 1) AS SplitDigits,
    3 * (SUBSTR(3987654321, idx, 1)) AS ConstTimesSplitDigits
   -- SUM(SUBSTR(2050364496, idx, 1) * (SUBSTR(5432765432, idx, 1))) AS Result
FROM (SELECT @cnt := 0) A
-- cross join any table has rows greater than or equal to your liking
CROSS JOIN (SELECT (@cnt := @cnt + 1) idx FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES LIMIT 10) B
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the format of number is fixed you just need some basic math:

```
SELECT num div          10 % 10 * 2
     + num div         100 % 10 * 3
     + num div        1000 % 10 * 4
     + num div       10000 % 10 * 5
     + num div      100000 % 10 * 6
     + num div     1000000 % 10 * 7
     + num div    10000000 % 10 * 2
     + num div   100000000 % 10 * 3
     + num div  1000000000 % 10 * 4
     + num div 10000000000 % 10 * 5 AS s
FROM (
    SELECT 20503644968 AS num
) AS t
-- 157
```

Answer (score 1):

> Then I have to sum all the multiplications. After that there's some
>   trivial calculations with the result of the sum, applying some modulus
>   and complements, but it's out of the scope of this question.

Why outside the scope off this question, as we love to solve these things.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
 11 - (SUM(vector_input.vector_input__summed) % 11)
FROM (

SELECT 
 vector.item * input.item AS vector_input__summed

FROM (
 SELECT 
  DISTINCT
    SUBSTRING(5432765432, vector_number_generator.number, 1) AS item
    ,  vector_number_generator.number  AS position
FROM (
  SELECT 
   @vector_row := @vector_row + 1 AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION   SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) AS row_1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @vector_row := 0 
  ) AS init_user_params 
) AS vector_number_generator

) AS vector
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
  DISTINCT
       SUBSTRING(2050364496, number_generator.number, 1) AS item
    ,  number_generator.number  AS position
FROM (
  SELECT 
   @row := @row + 1 AS number
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION   SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION  SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row2
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0 
  ) AS init_user_params 
) AS number_generator
) AS input
ON
 vector.position = input.position
) AS vector_input
```

**Result**

```
| 11 - (SUM(vector_input.vector_input__summed) % 11) |
| -------------------------------------------------- |
| 8                                                  |
```

See [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/31)

If modulus 10 should also be used which i assume it should be 
`((11 - (SUM(vector_input.vector_input__summed) % 11)) % 10)` see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ai83gaMJMJ7tRFLtTSzyzt/33)

Answer (score 0):

*Using [Nae's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56329923/3163120) and [Raymond's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56330307/3163120) answers*

#### To split a fixed-length number into separated rows

```
SELECT
   SUBSTR(1234567890123, range10, 1)
FROM (
  SELECT 1 range10
  UNION SELECT 2
  UNION SELECT 3
  UNION SELECT 4
  UNION SELECT 5
  UNION SELECT 6
  UNION SELECT 7
  UNION SELECT 8
  UNION SELECT 9
  UNION SELECT 10
  UNION SELECT 11
  UNION SELECT 12
  UNION SELECT 13
) A
```

*For a variable-length number of characters, see [Nae's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56329923/3163120) answer*

---

#### The whole RUC's validation made into a function

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `validate_ruc`(`ruc` BIGINT) RETURNS binary(1)
BEGIN
DECLARE isValid BINARY;

IF LENGTH(ruc) != 11 THEN RETURN FALSE; END IF;

SELECT
  ((11 - (sum % 11)) % 10) = (ruc % 10)
INTO isValid
FROM (
  SELECT
     SUM( SUBSTR(ruc, range10, 1) * (SUBSTR(5432765432, range10, 1)) ) AS sum
  FROM (
    SELECT 1 range10
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 4
    UNION SELECT 5
    UNION SELECT 6
    UNION SELECT 7
    UNION SELECT 8
    UNION SELECT 9
    UNION SELECT 10
  ) A
) B;

RETURN isValid;

END
```